# Passing multiple params issue in VUE.JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, rest, get

I am trying to get data by passing multiple ids as param.But the params i am passing is going as array which i don't want.

**Example:**

Current data: The api is returning param as details?ids[]=123&ids[]=245

Expected data: I would like to pass the param as details?ids=123&ids=245

```js
  const postRes = await axios.post('employee/departments', this.details);
  const getRes = await axios.get('employee/departments',
     { params: { ids: postRes.map(i=>i.id)},
  });
  this.$emit('fileDetails', getRes.data);
```

Comment: The method is working fine and returning GET api back.The issue is with passing params.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could serialize the parameters yourself:

1. Map each object into a string, containing `'ids='` prefixed to the object's `id`.
2. Join the resulting array with a `&` delimiter.

```js
const params = postRes.map(i => 'ids=' + i.id) 1️⃣
                      .join('&') 2️⃣
const getRes = await axios.get('employee/departments?' + params)
```

Run this snippet for example output:

```js
const postRes = [{ id: 11 }, { id: 22 }, { id: 33 }]
const url = 'employee/departments?' + postRes.map(i => 'ids=' + i.id).join('&')
console.log(url)
```